# Mono dllnotfound no matter what I do

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

i hope you can help me. I installed mono on my ubuntu system but when i try to start an application i get a dllnotfound-exception. The missing Dll is libgdiplus. I tried adding /usr/lib/ to the shared libraries and I tried to add the Dll to the mono config file. Both didn't work, but my system could find the .so file, when I looked for it, even ldconfig says it's there:

```
sudo ldconfig -p |grep libgdiplus
    libgdiplus.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.0
    libgdiplus.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so
```

But the error i get, when trying to start mono is still the same. But I got most curious when I tried to add the path to this library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envrionment variable, because when I tried, I found out this variable doesn't exist and when I set it to /usr/lib mono didn't care and give me the same Error messages

This is the console output I get when trying to run Mono:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GUI.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GUI.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is now solved. After hours and hours of tryng to get mono to recognize the path of libgdiplus I just reinstalled the library. Now this exception doesn't occur anymore(although another one is...:( )